# Get the AllowDrop propert of a Model in a ViewModel in WPF Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a model class ViewItem that has the property AllowDrop.  My View Model ViewModel is an observable collection of ViewItem.

The ViewItem property

```
    public bool AllowDrop
    {
        get
        {
            return _allowDrop;
        }
    }
```

I have a ViewTree thats data source is bound to an instance of the ViewModel, MyItems.

I would like to be able to access bind the ViewTreeItems AllowDrop property to the underlying model, however I can't figure out the correct way to access it.

My XAML for the TreeView looks like this

```
        <TreeView x:Name="ViewsTree"
                  AllowDragDrop="True"
                  DragOver="ViewsTree_DragOver"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ViewTemplate}"
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView>
```

I am stuck on how to access the ViewItem in the MyView collection to bind to the AllowDrop property.

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. It doesn't include a [mcve], but more critically, it's not clear at all why and how multiple values found in the data should map to a _single_ value in the view. What do you expect to happen if not all the view item `AllowDrop` properties have the same value. Whatever you expect, why do you feel that's an appropriate choice? It seems to me it would make more sense to put the property in a container view model object that references both the collection of items and that single property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bare minimum example.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="{Binding AllowDrop}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding AllowDrop}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new List<ViewItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            MyItems.Add(new ViewItem { Id = i, AllowDrop = i % 2 == 0 });
    }

    public List<ViewItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}

public class ViewItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool AllowDrop { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to drag something on the TreeListView will work on items with even Id only.